# Proof that an injective system with $i\notin\textrm{ran}{f}$ has a Peano subsystem.

Tags: set-theory, peano-axioms, natural-numbers

I follow [this link](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/courses/math140/peano.pdf), in particular Exercise 2 at the bottom of page 3.

**Def 1.** A *System* is a tripple $(X,i,f)$, where $X$ is a set, $i$ is called initial element, and $f$ is a function $X\to X$.

**Def 2.** $S_2$ is a *subsystem* of $S_1$ if (a) $S_2\subset S_1$, (b) $i_1=i_2$, and (c) $\forall x\in S_2[f_1(x)=f_2(x)]$. *proper subsystem* implies $S_1\ne S_2$.

**Def 3.** A *Peano's system* is a system $(X,i,f)$ such that (1) $f$ is injective, (2) $i\notin \textrm{ran}{f}$, and (3) $(X,i,f)$ has no proper subsystem.

**Lemma** Given a system $(X,i,f)$ such that (1) $f$ is injective, and (2) $i\notin \textrm{ran}{f}$, then $(X,i,f)$ has a Peano's subsystem.

**Proof**
A subsystem has the same initial element and the same function. We define a set using the axiom of separation:
$$
\hat{X}:=\{x\in X: x=i\lor \exists x'[x'\in \hat{X}\land x=f(x')]\}.   
\quad\quad(*)
$$
Now we prove that $(\hat{X},i,f)$ is a Peano's system. (1) $\hat{X}\subset X$ thus $f\mid_{\hat{X}}$ is injective. (2) Since $\textrm{ran}{f\mid_{\hat{X}}}\subset\textrm{ran}{f}$, follows that $i\notin \textrm{ran}{f\mid_{\hat{X}}}$. (3) Now suppose that $(\hat{X},i,f)$ has a proper subsystem $(\hat{X}',i,f)$. Then $\hat{X}'\subsetneq \hat{X}$ and there is an $x\in \hat{X}$ such that $x\notin \hat{X}'$. From $(*)$ we know that either $x=i$ or $\exists x'(x=f(x'))$. $x=i$ is not possible because, being $(\hat{X}',i,f)$ a subsystem, $i\in \hat{X}'$. We consider $x\ne i$, then from (*) we know that $x'\in \hat{X}$. Two cases again: $x'\in\hat{X}'$ leads to a contradiction since $f$ is defined on $x'$, and so on until reaching $i$ and getting a contradiction.

> How can I conclude the proof formally (case $x\ne i$)? I assume that the exercise should be "easy" since the proofs that follow are not very difficult. 
>   The proof should not include external results or the use *inductive* concept that is introduced later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your definition of $\hat{X}$ works, which is where the problems are coming from. Here, let me help you rebuild your approach a bit.

Every system $X$ has a smallest subsystem $\hat{X} \subseteq X$, which can be defined in a number of ways. One way is to define $\hat{X}$ as the intersection of all the subsystems (and to check that being a subsystem is closed under intersection).

After this, you should check that $\hat{X}$ has no proper subsystems. I haven't thought about it too carefully, but I think the relevant fact is:

> **Lemma.** Let $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$ denote an injective morphism of systems. Then the inverse-image function $\varphi^* : \mathrm{Sub}(Y) \rightarrow \mathrm{Sub}(X)$ is surjective. When restricted to the image of the direct image map $\varphi_* : \mathrm{Sub}(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{Sub}(Y)$, it's bijective.

Once you've proved this, define $\varphi : \hat{X} \rightarrow X$ to be the inclusion; you should be able to use the above lemma to ensure there's no extra subsystems lurking around.

Now define that a system $X$ is *injective* iff $f_X$ is injective, and *weakly acyclic* iff $0_X \notin \mathrm{img}(f_X)$. All that remains to be done is to prove that these conditions are preserved under the taking of subsystems. This is kind of obvious, so once you get this point, you're basically done.

Some further terms to look up:

- Monounary algebra
- Pointed monounary algebra
- NNO (natural numbers object)

Comment: Thank you. 1) what do mean by "doen't work"? do you mean wrong or that it leads to nothing? 2) what do you mean with smallest subsystem? $(\{i\},i,f)$ is the smallest subsystem. 3) The idea of the intersection of all subsystems with property 1&2 of Peano came to my mind, but I left it on the side as *ultima ratio* (because I estimated it as complex) The idea of an exercise should be to use the concepts introduced. That is what I'm looking for. Could be another proof strategy but in the given framework.

Comment: @LiPo, since you mention $\hat{X}$ in its own definition... it's not really a definition. Or at least, I don't think the separation axiom really works like that.

Comment: You are right, I can't use $\hat{X}$ inside the relation of the instance of ax. of separation. That is, my proof is wrong from the beginning.